# c++: heterogeneous template for bounded numbers

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a list (std::container or even list* would be ok) of numbers (int and double) that can have limits imposed on them.

```
template<typename T> 
class setting {
  public:
    std::string name, units;
    T value, min, max, step;

    setting(std::string n, T val) : name(n), value(val) { }

    setting operator++(int) {
      setting tmp = *this;
      value += step; if(value > max) value = max;
      return tmp;
    }
};
...
list.add(new setting<int>("channel", 4));
list.add(new setting<double>("amplitude", 5.6));
...
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  std::cout << list[i].name << ": " << list[i].value << std::endl;
```

I've tried this a couple of different ways but I'm not happy with any of them. Can't derive from a common base because the base type doesn't know about `value' because it doesn't know the type or has to have the type defined ahead of time. Tried it with macro templates but the downcast feels sloppy. Is there a way to do this without resorting to a union of all types with a type identifier to select the right member?

boost::variant with overloaded constructors seems to do what I want so far, except for having to enumerate all the types at compile time:

```
class setting {
   public:
      boost::variant<
         bool,
         int8_t,
         uint8_t,
         int16_t,
         uint16_t,
         int32_t,
         uint32_t,
         int64_t,
         uint64_t,
         float,
         double,
         std::string
            > value;

      std::string name;

      setting(std::string n, int v) : name(n), value(v) { }
      setting(std::string n, double v) : name(n), value(v) { }
      setting(std::string n, std::string v) : name(n), value(v) { }
};

typedef std::map<std::string, setting*> MapType;
typedef MapType::const_iterator MapItr;

int main() {
   MapType settinglist;

   settinglist["height"] = new setting("height", 1.3);
   settinglist["width"]  = new setting("width", 5);
   settinglist["name"]   = new setting("name", "the name");

   for(MapItr i = settinglist.begin(); i != settinglist.end(); ++i) {
      std::cout << i->second->name
         << " : " << i->second->value
         << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
};
```

gives:

```
height : 1.3
name : the name
width : 5
```

Comment: I wonder if this has already been addressed in a library.  APIs using name-value pairs are very common, as are min and max valid values for numeric properties.

Comment: To be clear, do you want value to yield a primitive, or one of the bounded types? Also, can it be any primitive or just ints and doubles?

Comment: "value" should only need to be a fundamental type, though I could see needing int64_t.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a common base class with virtual `toString` and `fromString` functions?  Then your for loop becomes:

```
list<setting_base> lst;
for( list<setting_base>::iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it )
     std::cout << it->name << ": " << it->toString() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Well, I'd like to be able to manipulate "value" in general; I just used stdout as an example. Converting to a string will get the value out, but then I'd need to convert to the appropriate numeric type to use it. This would probably be handy to have, but not the solution I had hoped for. For instance, I might want to pass "value" to another function that would take "double" or whatever. I had thought about having a function in the base class that could retrieve what T is and then cast from there.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your plain type in [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/operators.htm)?

```
template <class T, T max = numeric_limits<T>::max(), T min = 0>
class Saturate
    : boost::operators<Saturate<T, max, min>, T >
{
private:
    T _value;
    void normalize() {
        if(_value < min) _value = min;
        if(_value > max) _value = max;
    }
    void toNormal(T t) {
        if(t < min) return min;
        if(t > max) return max;
        return t;
    }
public:
    Saturate(T t = T()) : _value(toNormal(t)) {}
    T value() { return _value; }
    Saturate& operator+=(const Saturate& x)
      { _value += x._value; normalize(); return *this; }
    Saturate& operator-=(const Saturate& x)
      { _value -= x._value; normalize(); return *this; }
    ...
};
...
std::vector<Saturate<int, 1023, -1023> > volume;
...
volume[3] = 50000; // really loud
std::cout << volume[3].value(); // Not so loud
```

Comment: I want the vector to be heterogeneous, not knowing ahead of time what types I'll want in my list. You can mostly condense this down into an integer and a real list which would mean I'd need at most 2, but usually at least 2. I had hoped I just didn't know enough magic to put it together since it feels really close.

Comment: @lister - Ok, I was focused on the "on bounded members" part of the title, not "heterogeneous type" part. Have you looked at [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/any/s02.html)?

Comment: That was one of the ways I tried; you have to know the type you put in to any_cast your any back out. Assignment is clean, retrieval needs extra information. I'm looking at boost::variant right now. I also thought of using a union and overloaded accessors which might not be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to either fit everything into one type (meaning forget about int, just use double) or, define a more generic base type.

The problem that you noted with the generic base type is that it's, well generic. You're losing type information that you can't later get back when your accessing the elements in the container.

I think that your design goal is inconsistent. You should either create a generic interface that's good enough for your needs (that's type agnostic) or pick one type and stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying you could just provide a few `toInt` and `toDouble` and `toInt64` methods in your base class.  Then, if you need the double value, you just ask for it.  It requires a minimal amount of effort on everybody's part.

Failing that, you could replace a regular `virtual int value() const` method with a `virtual void value(Operator&) const` one.  `Operator` would provide virtual functions of its own that each accept one of the types you would want to act on.  Essentially:

```
struct Operator {
    virtual act(int) = 0;
    virtual act(double) = 0;
    //repeat for other types
};

struct Base {
    virtual value(Operator&) const = 0;
};
```

When you call `value` on your base type, virtual dispatch will ensure the correct implementation gets called. Within that implementation, you provide the proper static type to `act`, and overload resolution kicks in.  You can actually perform your calculations within the `Operator` instance, or just store the result and provide an accessor.  In the former case, you can do something unique for each type, like use an algorithm that works faster with integer types but without the precision.  In the later case, you can go one step further and provide a templated accessor within `Base`

```
struct Base {
    //other stuff
    template<typename Operator>
    typename Operator::ResultType value() const {
        Operator op;
        value(op); 
        return op.result();
    }
}
// later
cout << basePtr->get<IntGetter>();
```

Of course, the end result of that is an extremely convoluted way of doing what I initially suggested.

///////
I just noticed your edit to the original question.  With so many possible base types, this becomes much less feasible.  You have to provide overloads of each primitive type within your Operator classes.  You could provide default implementations to the base Operator class; like calling `act(int)` for all integral types and `act(double)` for all floating point types, then you'd be back down to just two required overloads per implementation, plus whatever additional ones you need for that specific use case.

But now I'm looking towards YAGNI.  You've got a complicated base class, just so you can provide settings that save a few bytes by not storing a full `int`?  Can you really not just store everything as a `double`?  That stores a whole bunch of integer values precisely.  Or use `boost::variant` and restrict yourself to ints, doubles, and strings.

Comment: I only did that to see if it would tolerate lots of types, though this is for instrument control and some functions actually do take a short specifically, so having that available would save yet another cast. I know IAGN all of that, so I'd leave out the more specific stuff, which could be stuffed in later if really needed. Also, playing with the variant stuff, I can templatize the member functions instead of the whole class and only have to enumerate them in the variant declaration.